# tar checkpoints not matching input

Tags: bash, tar

Consider the following command

```
tar acf file.tar.gz file-5.16 --checkpoint=1 --blocking-factor=50 \
  --checkpoint-action='ttyout=%u\r'
```

Here is the size of the input folder

```
$ du -bs file-5.16
2520025 file-5.16
```

Now with this command a checkpoint is passed every record, and a record in this
case is
`50 * 512 bytes = 25,600 bytes`. It follows that
`2520025 / 25600 ≈ 98 checkpoints`. So why am I getting

```
109
```

As the output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To start, you cannot just take the total bytes in the folder and divide it. You
must work with the individual files. For each file you need to

```
ceil(bytes / 512) + 1 = blocks
```

The plus one is because each file has an extra block

> at the end of the file there's a block containing all zeros

[§ 9.4 Blocking](http://gnu.org/software/tar/manual/html_section/Blocking)

After that you add the blocks for all files and divide by the blocking factor,
in this case 50

```
ceil(blocks / 50) = records
```

Some demo code

```
$ find file-5.16 -type f |
    xargs du -B512 --apparent-size |
    perl -MPOSIX -ane '$bk += $F[0]+1; END {print ceil $bk/50}'
109
```